Prometheus Alert for pod with failed readinessProbe
i deployed a new kube deployment, with an updated image version. however, the new pods container failed its readiness probe and i did not receive an alert. this is because the pod was still "Running", as failed readinessprobes do not cause a pod to restart. therefore no alert.
how do i configure an alert for failed readiness probes? i only want the alert to trigger if the pod is in "Running" state to avoid getting duplicate alerts for failed readiness and crashloops.
TLDR what is the promql to alert for a pod which has a container that has failed readiness but where the pod is running?
kube_pod_container_status_ready{} == 0 shows me all pods with a container that is not "Ready".
kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Running"} == 1 shows me all pods in a Running state.
How can i combine these two seperate queries into one query to show me all pods with at least 1 container in a not Ready state?

You can combine them by group_left:
kube_pod_container_status_ready{namespace="REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_NAMESPACE"} == 0 * on (pod) group_left kube_pod_status_phase{namespace="REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_NAMESPACE", phase="Running"} == 1

